# React, render single state/object multiple times

Tags: reactjs

My real application, is to use react to create a firefox addon, to maintain an object/state in a DOM-less scope, and then render an element to the currently active browser window. Multiple browser windows are present.

So as a small experiment, to see if react can do this, I was messing around with the Timer example on the reactjs main site.

```
var Timer = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {secondsElapsed: 0};
  },
  tick: function() {
    this.setState({secondsElapsed: this.state.secondsElapsed + 1});
  },
  componentDidMount: function() {
    this.interval = setInterval(this.tick, 1000);
  },
  componentWillUnmount: function() {
    clearInterval(this.interval);
  },
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div>Seconds Elapsed: {this.state.secondsElapsed}</div>
    );
  }
});

var rendered = ReactDOM.render(<Timer />, mountNode);
// i hope to do something here to render it to another node
```

Is it possible to render the same timer to multiple nodes? The state should be same, and if i modify state in that single object it should affect both. Is this possible?

Thanks!

Comment: For this to work, you will probably need stores and a dispatcher and pass down props to all Timers on tick/whichever event.  Consider redux.js/flux.js etc

Comment: Thanks @bhargavponnapalli may you provide some small samples please :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually tried a different method. I used a singleton object with an array of callbacks as a property. This array of callbacks stores innerMethods of all elements mounted which correspond to a particular event.

Ideally, you should do have a key value pair
`event` => [All functions to fire]

But for this example, I went for a rather primitive scenario where there is only one event. So it's just an array of call callbacks for that event(doSomething).

http://codepen.io/bhargav175/pen/rxNRxO

MyStore

```
let MyStore = {
     doSomething : function(v){
            MyStore.callbacks.forEach((callback)=>{
                 callback(v);
         });
     },
     callbacks :[],
     addSomethingListener : function(callback){
          MyStore.callbacks.push(callback);
     }
}
```

Everytime a component is mounted I do this,

```
componentDidMount(props){
     MyStore.addSomethingListener(this.doStuff.bind(this));

  }
```

which adds callbacks from each element to the Store and each of them gets fired when the event occurs.

Full code.

```
let MyStore = {
     doSomething : function(v){
            MyStore.callbacks.forEach((callback)=>{
                 callback(v);
         });
     },
     callbacks :[],
     addSomethingListener : function(callback){
          MyStore.callbacks.push(callback);
     }
}

/*
 * A simple React component
 */
class Application extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
     this.state = {'some_prop':0};
  }
  doStuff(val){
     this.setState({
         'some_prop':val
     });
  }
  componentDidMount(props){
     MyStore.addSomethingListener(this.doStuff.bind(this));
  }
  render() {
    return <div>
      <h1>Hello, ES6 and React 0.13!</h1>
      <p>
       {this.state.some_prop}
      </p>
    </div>;
  }
}

/*
 * Render the above component into the div#app
 */
React.render(<Application />, document.getElementById('app'));

React.render(<Application />, document.getElementById('yetanotherapp'));



MyStore.doSomething(5);
MyStore.doSomething(15);
MyStore.doSomething(25);
```

So, if you see, I fire the doSomething event and all the components are updated at different mount nodes. In your case, you could move your `tick` logic into doSomething. Just a start. Hope this has helped.

Comment: Thank you very much I will test this and study this! :) By chance could you please show the non-Es6 solution as well, it would help so I dont have to learn multiple things in one shot.

Comment: Ah so what you did here, was just create multiple components, and update them all huh? This is cool I'll do it like this if its the only way, I was just wondering if I could make it such that `this.state` refer to the same object.